# Are assignments in the condition part of conditionals a bad practice?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style

Let's assume I want to write a function that concatenates two strings in C.
The way I would write it is:

```c
void concat(char s[], char t[]){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (s[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
    }

    while (t[j] != '\0'){
        s[i] = t[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';

}
```

However, [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) in their book implemented it differently, particularly including as much in the condition part of the while loop as possible:

```c
void concat(char s[], char t[]){
    int i, j;
    i = j = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') i++;

    while ((s[i++]=t[j++]) != '\0');

}
```

Which way is preferred? Is it encouraged or discouraged to write code the way K&R do? I believe my version would be easier to read by other people.

Comment: Don't forget, K&R was first published in 1978. There's been a couple small changes in how we code since then.

Comment: Readability was very different back in the days of teleprinters and line-oriented editors. Mushing all that stuff onto a single line used to be *more* readable.

Comment: I'm shocked that they have indices and comparisons to '\0' instead of something like `while (*s++ = *t++);`    (My C is very rusty, do I need parens there for operator precedence?)  Did K&R release a new version of their book?  Their original book had extremely concise and idiomatic code.

Comment: Readability is a very personal thing - even in the days of teletypes.  Different people prefer different styles.  A lot of the instruction cramming had to do with the code generation.  In those days, some instructions sets (eg Data General) could cram several operations into one instruction.  Also, in the early 80s, there was a myth that using parenthesis generated more instructions.  I had to generate the assembler to prove to the code reviewer that it was a myth.

Comment: Note that the two code blocks are not equivalent. The first code block will not copy the terminating `'\0'` from `t` (the `while` exits first). This will leave the resulting `s` string without a terminating `'\0'` (unless the memory location was already zeroed).  The second code block will make the copy of the terminating `'\0'` prior to exiting the `while` loop.

Comment: @user949300 Full ack, I too stumbled across this. Especially with those noisy `!= '\0'` comparisons. That's neither classic C style nor does it contain any boolean zen. On the other hand, it doesn't use yoda condition reversal either. Confusing this code is very much...

Comment: To the close voters: while it pains me to admit it, this question is not _primarily_ opinion-based. There are objective reasons for preferring one over the other, and this is not some esoteric, contrived code. There really is a lot of code of both types in existence, and one is clearly superior to the other.

Comment: Personally, I find both quite reasonable, and the second example, to me, highlights the dependancy these values have with each other.  I would probably write something somewhere in between these two examples myself.  What bothers me about _both_ of these examples though is the lack of array safety.  what if `s[]` is already full?

Comment: @corsiKa: In Swift, i++ is gone, and assignments don't yield a value anymore, so almost 40 years later we have languages where this style absolutely doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I would argue that both versions are incorrect because they do no length checking. There are valid input values where the result is not a concatenated string but a memory overrun. The interesting question: Which version makes this flow more obvious?

Answer (score 78):

Always prefer clarity over cleverness. In yesteryears the best programmer was that whose code nobody could understand. *"I cannot make sense of his code, he must be a genius"*, they said. Nowadays the best programmer is that whose code anyone can understand. Computer time is cheaper now than programmer's time.

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good
>   programmers write code that humans can understand. (M. Fowler)

So, no doubt, I'd go for option A. And that is my definitive answer.

Comment: Very pithy ideology, but the fact remains that there's nothing wrong with assignment in conditionals. It's far preferable to early exit from a loop or duplicating code before and inside a loop.

Comment: @MilesRout There is. There is something wrong with any code having a side effect where you don't expect it, i.e. passing function arguments or evaluating conditionals. Not even mentionning that `if (a=b)` can easily be mistaken for `if (a==b)`.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek - Any decent IDE will flag such an assignment, thus explicitly highlighting the suspect area, making it less likely to mess up.  Great IDEs even have a one-click refactoring mechanism.

Comment: @Luke: "My IDE can clean up X, therefore it's not a problem" is rather unconvincing. If it's not a problem, why does the IDE make it so easy to "fix?"

Comment: @Kevin - Modern IDEs flag situations when there is a potential problem because **there is a potential problem**.  This could (for example) be because of missing parenthesis (`if(a = someFunction() == true)`).  After properly parenthesizing the expression, no warning is displayed.  This eliminates all would-be confusion regarding the order of evaluation in such an expression.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek  I agree with your general point, but code with side effects in conditionals is really not so uncommon: `while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)` as the first that comes to my mind.

Comment: @DanielJour Personally, I don't write this in one line anyway, both assignment and the check will be a separate line in the loop. It doesn't bother me to write a couple of additional lines to avoid the assignment in the condition once, and if it's more than once, I would extract it into a function anyway.

Comment: @Malcolm The only ways to write it outside of the loop condition have code duplication, the `break;` statement, or a separate function. Extracting it into a function should be fine, but the other two are not generally considered good practice, at best they'd be considered as less bad than an assignment inside the loop condition.

Comment: @hvd So what's wrong with a break statement?

Comment: @Malcolm As far as I'm concerned, not much, but then, I don't see too much of a problem with assignments in loop conditions either. As far as some others are concerned, it's a disguised `goto` and makes it harder to reason about code correctness. Which I think is a valid point of view, even if it's one I don't share.

Comment: @DanielJour Lol, I thought about that exact counter-example a few hours after writing the comment, haha. This one is OK, for a couple of reason : 1- C does not offer any kind of equivalent foreach stucture and 2- you are just assigning the loop variable here, just like you would in a for loop. Nothing like writing inside an array.

Comment: @LukeA.Leber What ? An IDE ? Please ! https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/images/0/0f/real_programmers.png

Comment: I'd love to know whether this concept will eventually kill code golf

Comment: -1 for _Computer time is cheaper now than programmer's time_, this is the mentality that causes computers to become slower after every major software update.

Comment: @JopV. It's a truth, nonetheless.

Comment: +1 "Considering that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place, if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"  B.W.Kernighan

Comment: I would just like to know what makes your "definitive answer" definitive?  :-)

Answer (score 33):

The golden rule, same as in Tulains Córdova's answer, is to make sure to write intelligible code. But I don't agree with the conclusion. That golden rule means to write code that the typical programmer who will end up maintaining your code can understand. And *you* are the best judge at who the typical programmer who will end up maintaining your code is.

For the programmers that didn't start with C, the first version is probably easier to understand, for reasons you know already.

For those who grew up with that style of C, the second version may well be easier to understand: to them, it's equally understandable what the code does, to them, it leaves fewer questions why it's written the way it is, and to them, less vertical space means that more context can be displayed on the screen.

You'll have to rely on your own good sense. To which audience do you want to make your code easiest to understand? Is this code written for a company? Then the target audience is probably the other programmers in that company. Is this a personal hobby project that no one will work on but yourself? Then you are your own target audience. Is this code you want to share with others? Then those others are your target audience. Pick the version that matches that audience. Unfortunately, there is no single preferred way to encourage.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT:** The line `s[i] = '\0';` was added to the first version, thereby fixing it as described in variant 1 below, so this doesn't apply to the current version of the question's code anymore.

The second version has the distinctive advantage of being **correct**, while the first one is not - it does not null-terminate the target string correctly.

The "assignment in condition" allows expressing the concept of "copy every character *before* checking for the null character" very concisely and in a way that makes optimization for the compiler somewhat easier, though many software engineers these days find this style of code less readable. If you insist on using the first version, you'd have to either

1. add the null-termination after the end of the second loop (adding more code, but you can argue the readabiliy makes it worthwhile) or
2. change the loop body to "first assign, then either check or save the assigned char, then increment indices". Checking the condition in the middle of the loop means breaking out of the loop (reducing clarity, frowned upon by most purists). Saving the assigned char would mean introducing a temporary variable (reducing clarity and efficiency). Both of those would annihilate the advantage in my opinion.

Comment: Correct is better than readable and concise.

Answer (score 5):

The answers by Tulains Córdova and hvd cover the clarity/readability aspects quite well. Let me throw in **scoping** as another reason in favour of assignments in conditions. A variable declared in the condition is only available in that statement’s scope. You cannot use that variable afterwards by accident. The *for* loop has been doing this for ages. And it’s important enough that the upcoming C++17 [introduces a similar syntax for *if* and *switch*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html):

```c
if (int foo = bar(); foo > 42) {
    do_stuff();
}

foo = 23;   // compiler error: foo is not in scope
```

Answer (score 3):

No. It is very standard and normal C style. Your example is a bad one, because it should just be a for loop, but in general there's nothing wrong with

```c
if ((a = f()) != NULL)
    ...
```

for example (or with while).

Comment: There is something wrong with it; ` != NULL` and its kin in a C conditional are natter, just there to placate developers who aren't comfortable with the concept of a value being true or false (or vice-versa).

Comment: @jcast No, it's more explicit to include `!= NULL`.

Comment: No, it's more explicit to say `(x != NULL) != 0`. After all, that's what C is *really* checking, right?

Comment: @jcast No, it isn't. Checking whether something is unequal to false is not how you write conditionals in any language.

Comment: "Checking whether something is unequal to false is not how you write conditionals in any language." Exactly.

Comment: by definition NULL will be promoted to '0' in context, so @Mike Rout is correct (but need not add insults).  Adding !=0 is a waste that will be optimized out anyway.  It's not what c is "really" checking.

Comment: Someone seeing `if (a=f())...` might think it could have been mistakenly typed by someone who meant `if (a==f())...`  The code `if ((a=f()) != 0)...`, however is equivalent, but someone seeing it would be unlikely to think the programmer meant `if ((a==f()) != 0)...`

Comment: I think OP used C because it's his language of choice, but the question is really language-agnostic regardless whether or not the exact syntax he used in his examples is 100% replicable in another language.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I agree with you, but I still think my answer is relevant. I don't think my answer is the one true correct answer and it shouldn't be accepted, though.

Comment: @jcast: This developer is very uncomfortable with pointers being true or false, or integers being true or false, because pointers ARE NOT true or false, and integers ARE NOT true or false.

Comment: @gnasher729 false and true are just 0 and something that isn't 0.

Comment: @MilesRout Well, no, they are not. false is false and true is true. They are enums. Saying that they have integer values is nonsense. C allows it. 40 years later, Swift doesn't.

Comment: @gnasher729 This isn't a question about Swift. It's a question about C. It's talking about C code, it uses C code as examples and I answered in the context of C. Mathematically speaking true and false can be defined and understood in many ways, but that's not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Even being able to do this at all is a very bad idea.  It's colloquially known as "The World's Last Bug," like so:

```c
if (alert = CODE_RED)
{
   launch_nukes();
}
```

While you're not likely to make a mistake that's *quite* that severe, it's very easy to accidentally screw up and cause a hard-to-find error in your codebase.  Most modern compilers will insert a warning for assignments inside a conditional.  They're there for a reason, and you'd do well to heed them and just avoid this construct.

Comment: Before these warning, we would write `CODE_RED = alert` so it gave a compiler error.

Comment: @Ian Yoda Conditionals that is called.  Hard to read they are.  Unfortunate the necessity for them is.

Comment: After a very brief introductory "getting used to it" period, Yoda conditions are no harder to read than normal ones.  Sometimes they are **more readable**.    For example, if you have a sequence of ifs / elseifs, having the condition being tested against on the left for higher emphasis is a slight improvement IMO.

Comment: @user949300 Two words: Stockholm Syndrome :P

Comment: `if (null === $clientAge)` HUH?? Null is always null, why are we testing, what.. ah wait, ok I see now..sigh

Answer (score 2):

Both styles are well formed, correct, and appropriate.  Which one is **more appropriate** depends largely upon your company's style guidelines.  Modern IDEs will facilitate the use of both styles through the use of live syntax linting that explicitly highlight areas that might have otherwise become a source of confusion.

For example, the following expression is highlighted by **Netbeans**:

```pl
if($a = someFunction())
```

on the grounds of "accidental assignment".

[image]

To explicitly tell Netbeans that "yeah, I really meant to do that...", the expression can be wrapped in a set of parenthesis.

```pl
if(($a = someFunction()))
```

[image]

At the end of the day, it all boils down to company style guidelines and the availability of modern tools to facilitate the development process.

Answer (score 2):

**In the days of K&R**

- ‘C’ was portable assembly code
- It was used by programmers that thought in assembly code
- The compiler did not do much optimization
- Most computers had “complex instruction sets”, 
  *for example `while ((s[i++]=t[j++]) != '\0')` would map to one instruction on most CPUs (I expect the Dec VAC)*

**There days**

- Most people reading C code are not assembly code programmers
- C compilers do lots of optimization, hence the simpler to read code is likely to be translated into the same machine code.

(A note on always using braces – the 1st set of code takes up more space due to having some “unneeded” `{}`, in my experience these often prevent code that has been badly merged from compiler and allow errors with incorrect “;” placements to be detected by tools.)

However in the old days the 2nd version of the code would have read.  (If I got it right!)

```c
concat(char* s, char *t){      
    while (*s++);
    --s;
    while (*s++=*t++);
}
```