# Do increment and decrement operators decrease readability?

Tags: java, c++, language-agnostic, readability, operators

I understand what increment and decrements operators are (`++` and `--`) and the difference between post and pre (`i++` vs `++i`) but should they be avoided as they do increase the difficulty of reading the code? After reading the answers to the question [Are assignments in the condition part of conditionals a bad practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/334910/are-assignments-in-the-condition-part-of-conditionals-a-bad-practice) it seems like code readability is of the utmost importance. I had a prof who told us not to use increment or decrement operators unless you know exactly what you're doing (but this prof usually gave poor advice).

In my opinion, `i++` is easier red than `i = i + 1`, however I wouldn't do this in side other statements, such as `arr[i++]` or `arr[++i]`, I would break these over two lines.

In summary

1. is it ok to use `++` and `--` when they are the only operations on the line?
2. is it ok to use `++` and `--` when they are combined with other operations and operator presidency has to be considered?

Comment: Regarding your Point 2, if you think there is any question about operator precedence, either simplify the code, or, if that is too wordy, add parentheses, **even if they are not needed.**

Comment: @user949300 I never thought of that. So you're saying `arr[(i++))]` is more clear than `arr[(i++)]` or are you talking only about when used in assignments e.g. `x = (i++);` I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: ++ is a method in Java which modifies its' parameters. Strange that you can't make your own method that modifies its' parameters.

Comment: @Celeritas I would say that the two example you cited were clear and don't need parens.  However, something like `x = y * 5 * ++i` needs them added.

Answer (score 6):

**Your question**

Yes it's completely ok to use `i++` and `--j` alone in a statement.  Most mainstream languages have adopted them.

Yes it's ok to use `i++` and `--j` in more complex expressions, when the precedence is self-explanatory :

- either because it's isolated enough as in `a[i++]`  or in `--j > 0`,
- or because it's used according to a common language idiom like `*p++` (*experienced C/C++ programmer know that increment applies to the pointer/iterator and not to the dereferenced value*).

**Additional advise**

Avoid in case of doubts! Prefer readability and simpler steps instead of using parentheses as for `**p[i]++`. Abuse like  `--(*p++)` or `1---j` should really be forbidden, not for syntactic ambiguity, but to the huge effort it requires to understand.

Absolute prohibition: Never use more than one such side effect on the same variable in the same expression as in `*p++ == *--p` or `funct(i++, i--)` .  This might lead at worst to undefined behavior, at best to misunderstandings as there are [subtle differences across languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25323426/3723423).

**Conclusion and quote of the day**:

> " Debugging is twice as hard as writing a program
>   in the first place. So *if you're as clever as you can be **when you
>   write it***, how will you ever debug it ? "
>
> B.W.Kernighan

Comment: --j > 0 is totally unreadable.

Comment: @gnasher729 I agree that there can be different appreciations on acceptability.  For me it seems clear because it is obvious that the decrement would not apply to the result of the comparison.  But maybe I'm overoptimisic here. I note that `a[i++]` is acceptable for you. `j-->0` would be confusing because of optical similarity with operator `->`.  But out of curiosity, how about `++j > 0` ?

Comment: @Christophe None of them are acceptable. "for me it seems clear because it is obvious that the decrement would not apply to the result of the comparison" The result of the comparison is a boolean, so this *is* obvious. What's not clear is whether the decrement happens before or after the comparison.

Comment: @Gardenhead It's obvious that the decrement happens before the comparison since it's a pre-decrement... the whole purpose of which is to decrement, then use the value.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor Again, that isn't obvious. You only know that because you memorized it. The fact that there are both pre- and post-decrement operators in the first place is a mistake. There should only be one, and in fact it should only mutate the value, not return the value that was mutated.

Comment: @gardenhead well, we all agree that professional programming is not a discipline that one can improvise.  One have to memorize a couple of things before writing meaningful programs.  It's like maths: most people find it obvious that * and / have precedence over + and - .  But it's not because some people could have difficulties to understand this basic property that you'll start to write all your formulas with extra parentheses or temporary variables to decompose the terms...

Comment: @Christophe Operator precedence is not at all "obvious" or "natural". There's no good reason why we should multiply before we divide. That's now how math works. It's why we have to memorize PEMDAS in school. It's been ingrained in us from an early age, but that doesn't make it right. Since most people are not taught decrement and increment operators in school, we don't have such preconceived notions.

Answer (score 4):

Let's walk through some logic:

1. Some junior developers don't fully understand these statements
2. So we avoid using them and limit their exposure to such statements
3. Eventually all developer will encounter such a statement
4. They misunderstand the statement because of #2

In a nutshell, when statements are avoided because they are considered esoteric they become more esoteric.  The problem is that if these things are part of the language, they will be found in code somewhere.  You might be able to prevent their use on a team but in a way you creating ignorance in doing so.

This problem is why I am not a big fan of "everything plus the kitchen sink" languages.  The more syntax there is, the more there is to understand and if some of it is kind of cruddy or awkward, it becomes esoteric and eventually causes a bug somewhere when it is misunderstood.  Adopting such a language and then declaring that people shouldn't use the syntax it offers isn't really optimal, in my opinion.  Python doesn't allow ++i and i++ and if you hate these statements, that's an advantage of that language.

In languages that allow these things, my answer is "know your tools".  These statements are well defined, quite logical, and are useful in common situations.  If you are programming in a language that allows these statements and don't know what they mean, you need to skill-up and it's not the responsibility of other developers to coddle you.

Comment: I fully agree. Following the logic of 1 and 2 we could also avoid ^ (XOR which could be confused with power) and bit shift `<<` and  `>>`  (confusion with inserter/extractor).   Someone will then recommend for readability sake to define macros for AND and for OR (after all, || is not a straightforward meaning by itself), and we'll end up with COBOL like language where `i++` is to be written `ADD 1 TO I` ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Ha! COBOL. I've been unlucky enough to have to parse COBOL both in the reading sense and the software sense.  My favorite statement is `NEXT SENTENCE` which moves to the statement following the next period, which is obviously obvious.

Comment: @Christophe I agree partly, programmers should know their language and disagree strongly: I wouldn't want my coworker using every arcane trick that's possible.Just because it can be done doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it.

Comment: @PieterB iI think that we agree completely: common use and idioms are ok; Ultra smart combined use of every feature bears a significant risk (see quote in my own answer). I upvoted Jimmy's answer because one cannot think about readability without keeping the audience in mind. But the considered audience should be programmers proficient in the language of the software to develop/maintain

Comment: @PieterB The point I am trying to make here is that when developers start exiling common parts of grammar from code, we end up with a situation where people can't easily read other people's code even though they write code in that same language.  There are a lot of valid arguments about by ++i and i++ were a bad idea to add to a given language but it happened and the tradition in many languages is to use these constructs whenever they are useful.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that you can stretch that argument for "any" language feature.I mean, use of gotos is strongly discouraged and for instance there's strong debate whether or not to use multiple exits in a method.About ++, yes programmers should know what it does.............But would it be invented today if it wasn't there?

Comment: @PieterB So a lot of this goes to the other point I am making.  These are decisions that ideally are made by the language designer(s).  The primary issue is that we have too many languages that contain all kinds of syntax that wasn't well considered.  When you are programming in Java, for example, goto isn't an option just as i++ isn't an option in Python.  These are two languages where some thought was put into what features should be added.  There are lots of things that weren't added because they weren't deemed worth adding.

Comment: @PieterB To continue briefly.  I use `i++` and `++i`.  I like these statements a whole lot.  I think they make a lot of sense.  I miss these statements in when I code in Python.  This is a subjective assessment but here's what's not subjective: it's valid syntax and it's unambiguous and well-defined.  Back to the subjective, `i++` and `++i` make a lot of sense.  When the `++` is before the variable, it's incremented before, after: after.   if you look at the AtomicInteger class which was created relatively recently.  There are methods with the exact same semantics as i++ and ++i.

Answer (score 3):

For question 1) - yes, it is perfectly readable. Every programmer on the planet understands the line `i++`.

*However*, for consistency's sake, one may consider using `i += 1` instead. It has the same form for any constant e.g. `i += 4`, whereas `i++` is a special bit of syntax that increments by exactly one.

For question 2) - absolutely not!! A programmer should never have to have memorized operator precedence to understand a line of code.

Comment: Coming from C++, I once accidentally created an infinite loop in Python as the loop body contained a `++i` statement :D Having gathered more experience since then, I find that increment operators such as `i++` are absolutely needed – I'd rather prefer to lose in-place addition `+=` than increment `++`. In `i += 1`, the `1` looks like a magic number, and the vast majority of increments *are* by one. Special syntax for the successor/predecessor is usually warranted. The only reason why Python gets away without such syntax are `range()` loops.

Comment: No, not every programmer on the planet. Swift programmers don't.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at two small code snippets (C# - I do not know if C++ and Java behave the same way as C# does):

```
int i = 0;
int j = i++;
```

and

```
int i = 0;
int j = ++i;
```

Do you understand the difference between those versions? What are the values of `i` and `j` in those snippets?

If you - and also your colleagues - can tell that without hesitation, then such use is OK, within your team. I prefer to discourage this type of use.

Comment: FYI: C#, Java, C++ and C have the same semantic for pre- and post-increment.  By the way, did you know that some years ago, some people found it too confusing to use `=` for assignment, because it was not consistent with the mathematical equality ?  This is why ADA uses `:=` and long before it APL opted for <-  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the language.** In C there are some well-known idioms which depends on using increments or decrements as expressions. So you would expect a C developer reading your code to be familiar with these idioms. The reader might be mystified if you choose a less idiomatic solution.

Java and C# have different culture and different idioms. It is not common to use increments in expressions. Doing it might be considered "clever" or "micro-optimization". Increment as stand-alone statements are not frowned upon though. (Although iterators and similar are preferred to loops with counters.)

Some languages like Python does not have increment/decrement operators at all, in which case you don't have much of a choice.

Bottom line: Readability is always relative to a certain audience.

Comment: Excellent conclusion !  By the way, Stroustrup told that the early C++ 1.0 had only a single operator++ overload for both preincrement and postincrement in user defined classes.  But he got enough requests from his then (C aware) small user community that he ended up adding both overloads. So it's really a matter of using popular language idioms.